# Proving two continuous functions coincide at 0 using a continuous piece function of the two

Tags: continuity, proof-writing, piecewise-continuity

I'm reviewing some old undergrad notes of mine and came across this continuity question.

"Let $f:(-\infty,0]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions on the entirety of their respective domains. Now let us define the function $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by:

$$h(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      f(x) & x\le{}0\\
      g(x) & x>0\\
    \end{cases}       $$
Show that $h$ is continuous at $c=0$ iff $f(0)=g(0).$" The backward implication was no trouble at all but I am having trouble in the forward direction.

My attempt:

Suppose $h$ is continuous at $c=0$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta_f,\delta_g,\delta_h>0$ that satisfy the definition of continuity at $f,g$ and $h$, respectively, at $c$ w.r.t the fixed $\epsilon$. Define $\delta:=\min(\{\delta_f,\delta_g,\delta_h\})$.

Now fix $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$.

**Case 1 $(x>0)$:**
$$|f(0)-g(0)|=|h(0)-g(0)|=|h(0)-g(x)+g(x)-g(0)|\le{}|h(0)-g(x)|+|g(x)-g(0)|$$
$$=|h(0)-h(x)|+|g(x)-g(0)|<2\epsilon$$

Which is true for any choice of $\epsilon>0$ which forces $f(0)=g(0).$ So we are done.

**Case 2 $(x\le0)$:**

$$|f(0)-g(0)|=|f(0)-h(x)+h(x)-g(0)|\le{}|f(0)-h(x)|+|h(x)-g(0)|=|f(0)-f(x)|+|h(x)-g(0)|$$

This is were I get stuck. Can this proof work in this way? Is there a nicer way to achieve the same result?

Hints would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just say, if $h$ is continuous at $0$ then

$$f(0)=h(0)= \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} h(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = g(0)?$$

Comment: Ah, bit annoyed I completely overlooked this. Thank you! A minor note, should the second limit be as x tends to 0 from the right hand side?

Comment: Oh yes you’re right.

Comment: Also, although this is a much better approach than what I was going for, do you know if doing the epsilon Delta way is doable without being ridiculously convoluted?

Comment: Yes, just use what I wrote and $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ to $g$ to prove that $\vert g(x)- f(0)\vert \lt \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ and therefore $f(0)=g(0)$.